# HTML тэг Video в IOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, html5

Есть следующий код, для отображения видео на сайте:

```
HTML:
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
    <source src="/path/" type="video/mp4" autoplay="true" ></source>
</video>
```

Требуется, что бы видео запускалось автоматически после загрузки страницы.
Все работает без нареканий, за исключением воспроизведения на Iphone, там пользователю надо сначала собственноручно нажать на видео, для воспроизведения.
Пробовал как методы из JS/Jquery:

```
.trigger('play') / .play()
```

Так и всяческие вариации HTML кода. Однако воспроизведения на Iphone так и не происходит.

Comment: там надо больше форматов видео, не только mp4 и ogv  но и webm и их любимый файл с расширением m4v

Comment: То бишь, проблема только в отсутствии нужных форматов?

Comment: ну да, ogv это для FF  а mp4. или m4v это уже для ios

Answer (score 0):

Помимо атрибутов `playsinline muted` обязательным условием автозапуска на iPhone является выключенный `Low Power Mode` на самом девайсе. А так в твоем коде есть все, чтобы автозапуск работал.